# Access to XMLHttpRequest ' from origin xxxx blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight. Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request

Tags: azure, google-chrome, browser, cors, azure-maps

I am using Azure maps and have no problem with FF or Edge. However Chrome is giving me the following error when trying to display the map:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at atlas.microsoft.com/map/tile/pbf?&view=Unified&language=NGT&api-version=1.0&layer=basic&style=main&zoom=16&x=12586&y=26496&subscription-key=xxxx' from origin mysite.org has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

I have added mysite.org to allowed origins in Azure. Some of the map contents do display such as the location marker and map style selector etc. Only the actual map is being blocked.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The CORS error is most likely a red herring here.
What's happening is that your request for some reason receives a redirect from the server, which therefore gets blocked by CORS 
It's likely that this particular URL is not intended to be consumed by Ajax but is meant to be rendered directly by a browser. It could, for example, be an authentication issue where the server is redirecting you to a login page or the map server may just want to reformat your URL.

In any case, open the developer tools in a browser, tell it to not clear the requests on navigation and try to put that URL in; you'll see that some kind of redirect happens in the network tab You then need to figure out how to avoid that redirect - or, if this URL type is not intended for Ajax, rethink your design.

I wrote a bit about how CORS works here; https://www.lytzen.name/2016/02/20/playing-with-cors.html, which may or may not help.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at your reference and try the browser steps you indicate. However, all I am doing is making a call to the following URL: [link]https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/js/atlas.min.js?api-version=1. Somewhere in there the redirect is happening.

Comment: I opened the offending URL in a browser with debugger attached and this is what I received: Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile. Not sure I have any control over that. Now what? Thanks

Comment: Did you open the network tab in the debug tools and tell it to not clear on navigate? You need to see those network requests and what the response codes are. The first one is likely a 302 and that'll be your problem.